# How to generate all possible pairings within a column in a dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 columns in a table which are IDs and their corresponding sequences (ie. TCGATCGA). I want to group this table by IDs and then generate all possible pairings of the sequences within each group.

For the grouping part, I am using df %>% group_by(IDs), but I am having issues with generating all possible pairings of the sequence.

What function would be good for generating these combinations, preferably without having to manually enter the sequences because I have over 1000? The end goal of generating these pairings is to be able to check the similarity between each of the sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use expand grid over the same column (vector)?

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
expand.grid(x, x)
```

If you don't want to return ID's that are the same and repetition:

```
t(combn(x, 2))
```

Comment: how could I avoid redundant pairings in that case?

Comment: also, is there a way to indicates which IDs the pairings are coming from in the expand.grid table?